# Probability - Avoiding Consecutive Placement of Objects

Tags: probability

**Problem:** Phyllis has a sampler box of containing $12$ different tea packets. Suppose she will drink all of these teas in a day, but there are three teas she doesn't want to drink consecutively. How many orders can she drink them in that avoid this problem?

I know since there are $12$ tea packets in total, we should first determine the spots of the $3$ teas that she doesn't want to drink consecutively and then decide the placement of the others. I am having trouble figuring this out though.

Any help is appreciated.

**My attempt:** I thought of this problem by using spaces. As in, she has 12 slots and she is going to plan out which tea she drinks in which slot.

**Step 1:** Place the three teas she doesn't want to drink consecutively.

For the first tea, there are $12$ spaces. For the second tea, there are $10$ spaces. For the third tea, there are $8$ spaces.  So there are $12\times 10 \times 8$ choices to place the three teas she doesn't want to drink consecutively.

**Step 2:** Place the remaining tea packets.

Since out of the $12$ tea packets total, we have already placed $3$, there are $9$ slots left to fill. So there are $9!$ ways to place the remaining $9$ tea packets for the day.

So there are $(12\times 10 \times 8)+9!$ orders.

Comment: What's the significance of the jasmine and matcha? If they're all different, why don't you just call them altogether $12$ different tea bags?

Comment: there were 4 parts to this question in total...the significance of the jasmine and the matcha was needed for the other parts of the problem. this is the fourth part to the problem

Comment: If you copy problems from somewhere, you should say so and provide the source. Also, if they contain irrelevant information and you don't want to edit it out (which in fact I think is a good idea, since people often edit out information that turns out to be relevant after all), it would make sense to point out that you're aware that it's irrelevant. It's rather unusual to post a question containing information that you know is irrelevant.

Comment: @joriki i will edit it

Comment: Does she not want to drink all three teas in a row, or does she not want to drink any pair of the three next to each other?

Comment: it just says "there are three teas she doesn't want to drink consecutively"...so i would think that she doesnt want to drink all three in a row...? @RossMillikan

Comment: @RossMillikan i attempted the problem..i am going to place my attempt above.

Comment: In step 1 you are trying to place the three of them *not* consecutively.  If you put the first one in the middle there are only $9$ places for the second, while if you put it at the end there are $10$.  If you put the first two far apart and not at the end there are only $6$ places left for the third but there could be as many as $8$.  You need a lot more work to get the number of ways to place the three, but it could be done.  In step 2 you are correct that there are $9!$ arrangements for the others, but you should multiply by it because each arrangement of the $3$ corresponds to $9!$ orders.

Comment: It also looks like in step 1 you are trying to make sure no two of them are consecutive.  That is a different problem from not have all of them consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $12!$ orders for all the teas.  We will subtract the ones that have the three teas all together.  There are $3!=6$ orders for the three teas among themselves.  Then we can group the three into one unit and note there are $10!$ orders for the nine other teas and the unit of three bad ones.  The total number of orders without the three together is then $$12!-6\cdot 10!$$

Comment: i will look this over...can you take a look at my attempt above?

Comment: i understand that there are $12!$ orders for all the teas and that there are $3!$ ways to order the three teas among themselves...why would we group the three teas into one unit if she doesn't want to drink them consecutively?

Comment: oh wait...are you subtracting what you don't want from the total number of arrangements? which would be that she does drink them consecutively?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: got it, thank you !